# button click does NOT update this.setState on first click; updates on Second Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying build my first calculator in React.
There seems to be a problem with my buttons (I think). 
While testing with `console.log`s, I discovered my first click of the addition button does NOT update all the setStates. Instead, the second click updates it correctly.

ANY idea why it isn't working?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class calculator extends Component {
    state = { 
        xxxxx:0,
        v1:0,
        v2:0,
        isCal:null

     }

    makeAdd = () => {

        const firstNum = this.state.xxxxx;

        this.setState({
            v1:firstNum,
            xxxxx:0,
            isCal:"add"
        });

        console.log("Add, firstNum is " + firstNum );
        console.log("and v1 is: " + this.state.v1);
        console.log("and isCal is: " + this.state.isCal);

        document.getElementById('DaInserting').innerHTML = null;

    };


    okInsert = (num) => {
        let ss = document.getElementById('DaInserting').innerHTML += num;

        this.setState({xxxxx:ss})
    }

    deAnswer = () => {


        let SecondNum = this.state.xxxxx;

        this.setState({v2:SecondNum})



        console.log("deSecond :" + this.state.v2);
        console.log("this.setState.isCal :" + this.state.isCal);


        let answer = 0;
        this.setState.v2 = this.state.xxxxx;
        if(this.state.isCal==="add") {
            answer = this.state.v1 + this.state.v2;
            console.log("and the answer is :" + answer);
        }

        document.getElementById('DaInserting').innerHTML = answer;

        //this.thenReset();
    }

    thenReset = () => {
        if (this.setState.isCal !== null) {
            this.setState({xxxxx:0})
            this.setState({v1:0})
            this.setState({v2:0})
            this.setState({isCal:null})
        }
    }



    render() {
        //console.log("\nALL states\nthis.state.xxxxx :" + this.state.xxxxx + "\nthis.state.v1 :"+ this.state.v1);

        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div style={{height:64}} className="col-12 card-body m-2 shadow-sm rounded bg-light" id="DaInserting"> </div>
            </div>    
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(7)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">7</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(8)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">8</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(9)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">9</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={this.makeDivide} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">/</div></div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(4)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">4</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(5)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">5</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(6)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">6</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={this.makeMultiply} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">x</div></div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(1)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">1</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(2)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">2</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(3)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">3</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={this.makeSubtract} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">-</div></div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6"><div onClick={this.deAnswer} className="btn btn-warning btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">=</div></div>
                {/* <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(".")} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">.</div></div> */}
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={() => this.okInsert(0)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">0</div></div>
                <div className="col-3"><div onClick={this.makeAdd} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-2 btn-block ">+</div></div>
            </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default calculator;
```

I have a div called "DaInserting" while gets updated as the user clicks on any number keys, then when the user will click on addition/subtraction/etc, `v1` should get updated, but it doesn't. It gets updated on the second click:- check `console.log`.

After the user has clicked additions/subtraction, "DaInserting" gets a reset, user clicks some numbers again, and then clicks the result button which should then check what the user choose (addition/subtraction)

Comment: `setState` is async, so any console.log immediately after `setState` is not guaranteed to display the new value. To check it, either use the callback or try logging it inside the `render` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, `setState` is asynchronous (see [these docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) for more on this), so you cannot rely on state updating right after calling `setState`. Instead, you generally need to wait until the next render for state values to update.

To get around this, you can pass a callback function (as a second argument) to `setState`, or use `await`, or use the new values that you're updating state with directly. Here I'd recommend using that last option. Also, it's usually a good idea to only call `setState` right before exiting a function, to avoid async confusion.

Here is an example how you might update the `deAnswer` method:

```js
deAnswer = () => {
    let answer = 0;
    if (this.state.isCal === "add") {
        answer = this.state.v1 + this.state.xxxxx;
        console.log("and the answer is :" + answer);
    }

    this.setState({
        v2: this.state.v1,
        answer: answer,
    })
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div id="DaInserting">{ this.state.answer }</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note also I've removed the setting of `innerHTML`, since you can and should change the content of the `"DaInserting"` div through rendering with state variables, not direct DOM manipulation.

Also consider checking out the [Intro to React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), it's a nice read and will help you in learning and building with React.

Comment: thank you sir. confused about one thing, what's the harm in using innerHTML?

Comment: @adnantariq there is the possibility of vulnerability to XSS attacks when using `innerHTML`, though that's not really a concern here. Mostly the problem is that it's not best practice, whereas using `state` and `render` to modify displayed content is. In more complex examples, using `innerHTML` can become cumbersome and make it harder to read the code.

Answer (score 2):

It tested your code and it is updating the state correctly, remember that setState() is an asynchronous function, so if you wanna check correctly add the function as a callback to be executed after the state is updated, like this:

```
this.setState({ v1:firstNum, xxxxx:0, isCal:"add"}, () => {
      console.log("Add, firstNum is " + firstNum );
      console.log("and v1 is: " + this.state.v1);
      console.log("and isCal is: " + this.state.isCal);
      console.log(news)
});
```